# Fetching purchase and subscription information on iOS

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

Note that I have absolutely no clue about developing iOS applications, let alone knowing their subscription handling. I am an Android guy. But, let me give a brief explanation on what we are doing on our Android applications.

We have in app purchases and subscriptions that we track down from our database, saving the important information fetched from [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions). The link redirects to the subscription details body, where we almost use all of the information and record them, some kind of similar process is also followed for in-app purchases.

From the device, we contact our backend server with the order ID and purchase token, where the server fetches the information from the developer API itself using that purchase token, then sends a response to the client, while recording the data to our database in background. For Android side, purchase token is enough to get the information.

On the other hand, I don't know how to handle this on iOS. I've tried searching for a similar API but unable to find it, maybe I am not experienced enough in that area, or it doesn't exist, so here I am. The only thing I know is that I need to implement [Server to Server notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_server-to-server_notifications) where it will report the subscription changes to our backend server, which, we will also record. But, I was unable to find a specific API for fetching the product details and latest subscription details like Google Play Developer API does.

How is it handled on iOS side? Do we need to send all the information from the device itself for example? Or is there an API that I couldn't find yet?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to solve it. We will wait for the client to send its transaction ID as well as server-to-server-notifications system to send its notification, then, when the transaction IDs matched, we will record the necessary information and then remove both informations from the cache.